# how to pack multiple list values in single csv cell using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variables degree and skill. For one candidate degree will have single value but skill will have multiple values.
To store these values for multiple candidates I append these values in lists degrees and skills respectively. But problems is, for each candidate skills get inserted in new rows and I want them in single cell separated by comma as shown in expected output. Kindly advice

```
    Actual Output:
    Deg                              SK
    []                               Sales
    Autonomous College Bhawanipatna  Channel Sales
    
    Expected Output:
    Deg                                SK               
    Autonomous College Bhawanipatna    Sales, Channel Sales
    
    degrees=[]
    skills=[]
    candidates = []
    for candidate in candidates:
      edu = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="pv-skill-category-entity__name-text t-16 t-black t-bold"]')
      for e in edu:
          skill = e.text
          skills.append(skill)
    
    degree = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="pv-entity__comma-item"]').text
    degrees.append(degree)
    file = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(degrees, skills)),columns=['Deg', 'SK'])
    file.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that

```
 skill = e.text
```

gives a string of characters.

You can modify you code as follows :

```
degrees=[]
skills=[]
edu = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="pv-skill-category-entity__name-text t-16 t-black t-bold"]')
for e in edu:
    skill = e.text
    skills.append(skill)

# This line transform the previous list into a string  that adds a comma in between elements which is inside a list.
skill_value = [', '.join(skills)]

degree = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="pv-entity__comma-item"]').text
degrees.append(degree)
file = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(degrees, skill_value)),columns=['Deg', 'SK'])
file.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: this is will work for one candidate only. however i m fetching details from multiple candidate using for loop on the top.  Suggested line of code clubs together skills of all candidates together. However I want skills of one candidate in one cell and other's in separate cell.

Comment: Could you give a minimal, reproducible example  ?

Comment: have updated my question. I have list of candidates. Each candidate has elements "edu" and each elements has variable "degree" and "skills". for each candidate there is only one "degree" but multiple "skill". In my degrees and skills list, details of each candidates should be amended in separate row like row1-degree, skill11, skill12, skill3, row2-degree, skill21, skill23. for each candidate degree should be in one column and all skills in single column(single cell). hope it is clear now

Comment: It is still not very clear. In your code, you loop candidates which is an empty list ? It will be much easier to help if there was a minimal, reproducible example. Or at least give an example of the input.

Comment: 'candidate = ['abc', 'xyz']
abc_degree = 'MBA'
abc_skills = ['WORD', 'EXCEL']
xyz_degree = ['BCOM']
xyz_skills = ['Java', 'PHP']' I need pandas csv with two rows on each for candidate xyz & abc and two columns, one each for degree and skill

Comment: If you could unpack your information in a dictionary form everything will be a lot easier. Having the name of the candidate inside the name variable for degree and skills make it hard to automate the process. Unpacking the information into something more like this would be better : candidates = {'acb': { 'skill': ['WORD', 'EXCEL'], degree = ['MBA']} 'xyz': { 'skill': ['Java', 'PHP'], degree = ['BCOM']} .

Comment: Above one seems a solution but in the mean time I came up with workaround. My problem was with skills column, where each candidate had many skills and while amending Skills list for all candidates, each skill of candidate was getting inserted into  new row which I didn't. I used your previous solution (join string method) with little modification to get desired result. I created a sublist inside loop, storing skills of one candidate>converted those into one string>amended that string into my main Skill list>cleared that sublist to make that ready to store skills of next candidate. thanks buddy